# How to take a screenshot of GMaps Frame and turn it into an image with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, html2canvas

I have an issue while turning a *Google Maps frame* to a base64 image, as you can see below the frame is saved but the map is not shown inside it.

[image]

I am wondering why it is not taking the inside of the frame.

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Lindow/gvy1x7kf/6/

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save PNG"/>
<hr>
<div class="elements" id="map"></div>
<div class="elements" id="img-out"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function() { 
    $("#btnSave").click(function() { 
        html2canvas($("#map"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                theCanvas = canvas;
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                // Convert and download as image 
                Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
                $("#img-out").append(canvas);
                // Clean up 
                //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
            }
        });
    });
}); 

var map = new GMaps({
    div: '#map',
    lat: -12.043333,
    lng: -77.028333
});
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Your fiddle just throws an error that Canvas2Image does not exist ...

Comment: @CBroe Still the issue is not because of this, I fixed it, and there's still the same error.

Comment: Error is still the same in your fiddle, I don’t see any update.

Comment: @CBroe Canvas2Image had nothing to do with my function since it was used to download the image to the computer. Check my answer below for the solution.

Comment: I didn’t say it had directly to do with it ... I just wanted you to fix that error first, so that we could see what other errors/warnings related to the problem it might throw afterwards (and a tainted canvas usually at least leaves a warning in console.)

Comment: @CBroe alright no problem :) you can see my updated answer for more precise troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to add `useCORS: true,` inside `html2canvas($('#id'), {...});`.

**What `useCORS` is used for ?**

*Cross-origin resource sharing* is a standard for accessing web resources on different domains.

**JSFiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/Lindow/60yn2hss/

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#btnSave").click(function() { 
    html2canvas($("#map"), {
        useCORS: true, #<--- here
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            theCanvas = canvas;
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            $("#img-out").append(canvas);
        }
    });
});
```

**output:**

[image: output.]

Know more here : https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html